# SQL Syntax to group this data in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, summarization

I have a table (called StayDate) which looks like this:

```
ResaID      Date        RoomCategory    RateAmount
 1       2014-09-01         A              125
 1       2014-09-02         A              125
 1       2014-09-03         B              140
 2       2014-09-04         A              125
 2       2014-09-05         A              125
 2       2014-09-06         A              125
 2       2014-09-07         C              160
 2       2014-09-08         C              160
```

The output from the SQL syntax I'm after need to look like this:

```
ResaID      Count        RoomCategory    RateAmount
 1            2             A              125
 1            1             B              140
 2            3             A              125
 2            2             C              160
```

Can anyone help with the SQL syntax needed to summarize the data as above?

Comment: `SELECT ResaID, COUNT(*) [Count], RoomCategory, RateAmount FROM YourTable GROUP BY ResaID, RoomCategory, RateAmount`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do this without a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ResaID, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ResaID, RoomCategory, RateAmount) Count, RoomCategory, RateAmount
FROM StayDate
```